# How to change the appearance of a button when it is clicked to show an arrow, using css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I want to change the appearance of a button when it its clicked to show an arrow coming out of it. I would like to do it using css. I am building a react application using typescript.

When the next button is clicked the arrow should be removed from the first one and go to the next one.

I have included a picture of the desired outcome.

[image]

Here is an example of 2 of the buttons:

```
 <div className="button-container">
                <Button
                  className="text-white font-nunito text active"
                  onClick={() => onFieldAdd('textField')}
                >
                  <TextFieldsIcon />
                  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Box</p>
                </Button>
                <Button
                  className="text-white font-nunito text mx-2 pr-15"
                  onClick={() => onFieldAdd('imageField')}
                  disabled={!!formId}
                >
                  <AddPhotoAlternateIcon />
                  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Image</p>
                </Button>
              </div>
```

Comment: Use `useState` to save the initial selected button or `null` if none is selected by default. When pressing a button (listen for the `onClick` event on each of them), set your state to the pressed button. And finally, use conditional rendering (using these operators: `&&` or `?:`) to show the arrow for the currently selected button.

Comment: Could you perhaps put that in a code example for me??

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution you're looking for:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const YourComponentName = () => {
    const [selectedBtn, setSelectedBtn] = useState(null);

    const hanldeClick = (e) => setSelectedBtn(e.target.id);

    return (
        <div>
            <button id="btn1" onClick={hanldeClick} className={selectedBtn === "btn1" ? "hasArrow" : ""}>
                Button 1
            </button>

            <button id="btn2" onClick={hanldeClick} className={selectedBtn === "btn2" ? "hasArrow" : ""}>
                Button 2
            </button>

            // SAME THING FOR THE REST OF THE BUTTONS
        </div>
    )
}

export default YourComponentName;
```

Just customize it to suit your use case.

Here, I am initializing a state called `selectedBtn` to `null` by default, and listening for `onClick` events on all of the buttons to change that state to the clicked button `id`. Once it changes, component will rerenders and the CSS class `hasArrow` will be added to the appropriate button element by checking if `selectedBtn` state value is equal to the button `id`, with the help of the ternary conditional operator `?:`.